# No such file or directory .zshrc

Tags: macos, shell, zsh

Recently, I realized I haven't been able to run

```
. .zshrc
```

in my home directory. It gives me the error above.
It's really strange and it's bugging me out since it's worked perfectly fine in the past.

In the *same directory*, any of the below commands work fine

```
. ~/.zshrc
source .zshrc
```

Output from `echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'`

```
/Users/prashanthcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin
/Users/prashanthcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/bin
/Users/prashanthcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin
/Users/prashanthcr/.nvm/versions/node/v5.5.0/bin
/Users/prashanthcr/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
/Users/prashanthcr/Library/Android/sdk/tools
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/opt/X11/bin
/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
/Users/prashanthcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin
/Users/prashanthcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/bin
/Users/prashanthcr/.rvm/bin
```

Using zsh on OS X 11.11.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`zsh` is working as expected (see `man zshbuiltins`):

- `. File` searches `$PATH` to find `File` unless there is a `/` in the name; while
- `source` is almost the same as `.`, except that it searches the working directory first.

I don't know how `. .zshrc` worked previously, unless there was a bug in an earlier release of `zsh`.

You can:

1. `alias .=source`;
2. link `~/.zshrc` to a directory in `$PATH`;
3. add your home directory to `$PATH` (not recommended); or
4. live with having to type `. ./.zshrc` (this is what I always do in `bash`, where `.` and `source` are identical, and I want to be sure of the location of the script).

Comment: Thanks for the man reference. I guess I may have mixed it up with bash, which apparently does look in the current directory when POSIX mode is turned off (which seems to be the normal setting).

Comment: Thanks for the comment on `bash`: I hadn't realised `.` and `source` check the current directory, but _after_ finding no match in `$path`, whereas `source` in `zsh` checks it first. I missed it because I tested with two files of the same name, one in the current directory, the other in `$path`.